# calculating similarity between two profiles for number of common features

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, similarity, unsupervised-learning

I am working on a clustering problem  of social network profiles and each profile document is represented by number of times the 'term of interest occurs' in the profile description. To do clustering effectively, I am trying to find the correct similarity measure (or distance function) between two of the profiles.

So lets say I have following table of profiles

```
            basketball  cricket python
profile1        4           2     1
profile2        2           1     3
profile3        2           1     0
```

Now, going by calculating euclidean distance, I get

```
distance (profile1,profile2) = 3
distance (profile2,profile3) = 3
distance (profile3,profile1) = 2.45
```

Now, this is fine, but there are two questions coming to my mind

Here we are disregarding number of features that are common, for example, even though profile 1 and profile 3 are nearest, going by human intuition, profile 1 and profile 2 at least have some value in all three interests -basketball, cricket and python and hence these two profiles likely be more similar rather than profile 1 and profile 3 where one of them(profile 3) does not mention python in profile. I also don't want just count of similar features for distance which will yield surely wrong results.

My first question - Is there any way I can accommodate this intuition by any of the established ways?

My second question - there can be some profile authors more verbose than others, how to adjust this? because verbose author of profile having 4 occurrences of python may be same as less verbose author 2 occurrences of python.

I was not able to come up with good title for the question. So sorry if its confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compute your profiles as you already did. Then the crucial step will be some kind of normalization. You can either divide the numbers by their total so that the numbers sum up to 1, or you can divide them by their Euclidean norm so that they have Euclidean norm 1.

For instance, using sum normalization, the first profile would become (rounded)

```
0.57, 0.29, 0.14
```

and using Euclidean normalization, it would become

```
0.87, 0.44, 0.22
```

This will make sure that all profiles are represented in the same numeric range, and will take care of the "overly verbose profile author".

---

Below is an example IPython session that shows how to normalize the rows by row sum and how to compute the Euclidean distances between the normalized rows. You will see that after normalization, profiles 1 and 3 are much closer together, as you would expect.

```
In [22]: p = array([[4,2,1],[2,1,3],[2,1,0]])

In [23]: p
Out[23]: 
array([[4, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [2, 1, 0]])

In [24]: p = p / p.sum(axis=1)[:,newaxis]

In [25]: p
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0.57142857,  0.28571429,  0.14285714],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.16666667,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.33333333,  0.        ]])

In [26]: p.sum(axis=1)
Out[26]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])

In [27]: norm(p[0] - p[1])   # distance 1-2
Out[27]: 0.44543540318737401

In [28]: norm(p[0] - p[2])   # distance 1-3
Out[28]: 0.17817416127494959

In [29]: norm(p[1] - p[2])   # distance 2-3
Out[29]: 0.62360956446232352
```

---

Finally, if you want to put more weight on whether a profile mentions an interest at all and not so much on how often it mentioned it, you can do an extra step before normalization: simply compute `pow(x, alpha)` for every element `x` of your profile vectors, where `alpha` is a parameter between 0 and 1. Here, 1 means standard linear weighting as before, and as you make alpha close to 0, it means only mentioning the interest counts, not how often. For instance, with `alpha = 0.5` (taking the square root of the profiles), we get:

```
In [32]: p = array([[4,2,1],[2,1,3],[2,1,0]])

In [33]: p = sqrt(p)

In [34]: p
Out[34]: 
array([[ 2.        ,  1.41421356,  1.        ],
       [ 1.41421356,  1.        ,  1.73205081],
       [ 1.41421356,  1.        ,  0.        ]])

In [35]: p = p / p.sum(axis=1)[:,newaxis]

In [37]: norm(p[0] - p[1])   # distance 1-2
Out[37]: 0.2353133053319465

In [38]: norm(p[0] - p[2])   # distance 1-3
Out[38]: 0.27881275777438091

In [39]: norm(p[1] - p[2])   # distance 2-3
Out[39]: 0.51412606310632747
```

Now profiles 1 and 2 are the closest match since we put more emphasis on the fact that they both mention Python, not so much on how often they mention it.

Comment: ok. But what about question 1? How to account for number of common features and distance?

Comment: @Kognizant: This takes care of both problems. Just compute the distance on these normalized vectors.

Comment: sorry but I did not understand. Could you please elaborate how it addresses the first problem?

Comment: @Kognizant: I have updated the answer with example code.

Comment: @Kognizant: I have also added one more nonlinear weighting idea which should give you what you want.

Comment: sounds good to me. Just one humble request, could you please update your answer with pow(x,05) step as well. just for continuity.

Comment: @Kognizant: I added the result, do you mean I should put the code as well?

Comment: just a request. If you are ok posting the code. If not, you've helped me already :)

Comment: @Kognizant: It's there ;)